# Predicting board values using CNN

Tags: python-2.7, tensorflow, convolution

I'm attempting to build a CNN in tensorflow which takes as input a vector ex:

x =[4, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 3],

Where the integers represent nominal encoding.

and outputs a vector where a value has shifted, ex:

y = [0, 4, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 3]

where in this case the position of the 4 is the changing variable in the vectors.

Question:

Is this possible to create a convnet that returns an output of that format? I've only ever seen a convet applied to classification problems.

How would I define/compute the error in these cases? Do I need to know the number of potential values for y?

Comment: someone deleted the answer I upvoted?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Question

*How can I use TensorFlow (and possibly Convolution) to play a board game?*

Specifically I have a small board ( 4x4 or 16x1 ) with possible values of [0,1,2,3,4] and I want to know the next best move.

## High Level Answer

What you are asking for isn't much different than [what DeepMind did with AlphaGo](https://gogameguru.com/i/2016/03/deepmind-mastering-go.pdf), but perhaps you don't need all the bells and whistles.  Reviewing how DeepMind arranged their architecture will give you a great insight into how you could apply a similar strategy to your game.

At a high level they used 1 neural net to grade the current board configuration (*the value network*) and another neural net to suggest the possible next best move (*the policy network*) together with a Search.

Yes, you could go to town with this configuration and your system would probably play an awesome game.

## Practical Next Steps

*I'm an Engineer and as such I like to see some results immediately, so that's what this section is really about.*

I've programmed AI for checkers using simple [AlphaBeta](https://www.npmjs.com/alphabeta) (built by following [this lecture](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=STjW3eH0Cik) from MIT).  I'd start with that, apply AlphaBeta to your board game and hardcode a *value function*.  For example a *value function* in checkers could be *"have more pieces than your opponent"*.

You will know if you've implemented it well if a **N+1** lookahead usually beats a **N** lookahead

**Then** it's time for TensorFlow!  Use your hardcoded value function and several lookaheads as your training set of *good moves*.  Train a CNN from TensorFlow to correctly weigh the higher lookahead moves as high.

Specifically, for move A from lookahead 1 vs move B from lookahead 2 vs move C from lookahead 3, your CNN should grade move C with the highest value, followed by move B, then move A, then all other possible moves.

If you can get a CNN to value a move 3 lookaheads from your hardcoded policy then effecitively your CNN in one lookahead has the power of your hard coded policy when your hard coded policy has 3 lookaheads.

Now switch out your hard coded policy and put in your CNN version 1.

Iterate and train your CNN version 2 just like you did version 1.

## Further next steps

The above is just to get something up and going.  It won't recreate AlphaGo.  Investigate the [Monte Carlo method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monte_Carlo_method) of playing very open games like Go. Also investigate more into a *"policy network"* to generate possible next moves instead of just grading them after generation.

Good luck!

## Final Tip

Convert all those numbers [0,1,2,3,4] into a 1 hot encoding using something like

```
board = tf.constant( [4, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 3] , dtype=tf.int16 )
board_as_mask = tf.one_hot( board , 5 )
sess = tf.Session()
sess.run(board_as_mask)
array([[ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  1.],
    [ 0.,  1.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
    [ 0.,  1.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
    [ 0.,  1.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
    [ 0.,  1.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
    [ 0.,  0.,  1.,  0.,  0.],
    [ 0.,  1.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
    [ 0.,  0.,  1.,  0.,  0.],
    [ 0.,  1.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
    [ 0.,  1.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
    [ 0.,  1.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
    [ 0.,  0.,  1.,  0.,  0.],
    [ 0.,  0.,  1.,  0.,  0.],
    [ 0.,  1.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
    [ 0.,  1.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
    [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  1.,  0.]], dtype=float32)
```

## How would I define/compute the error in these cases?

The error is usually sum of squares (**y_** - **y** )^2 or cross entropy **y_** * log(**y**). No need to do anything more fancy than that.  **y_** could be "is this the move that a N lookahead would choose that a N-1 wouldn't" or if you are using monte carlo, it could be "does this move lead to a win?"

## Do I need to know the number of potential values for y?

You could instead of using a 1-hot encoding, use a embedding_lookup like **tf.nn.embedding_lookup** and populate it with thousands of randomly initialized items.  If during training it encounters a new item then it will just start to update the respective embedding.

## Example Embedding Lookup

If you wanted to go with an embedding lookup (which could have serious advantages), you'd kick start it with something like this:

```
board = tf.constant( [4, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 3] , dtype=tf.int32 )

index_max = 10
features = 3
embeddings = tf.Variable( tf.truncated_normal( [index_max, features] , dtype=tf.float32 ) )
board_as_embeddings = tf.nn.embedding_lookup(embeddings, board)

sess = tf.Session()
sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer() )

print sess.run(board_as_embeddings)
```

and the output

```
[[-0.29756528  1.25859058 -1.68821394]
 [ 0.19683863  1.09903252 -1.12252223]
 [ 0.19683863  1.09903252 -1.12252223]
 [ 0.19683863  1.09903252 -1.12252223]
 [ 0.19683863  1.09903252 -1.12252223]
 [ 1.07770884 -1.47092581 -1.85934114]
 [ 0.19683863  1.09903252 -1.12252223]
 [ 1.07770884 -1.47092581 -1.85934114]
 [ 0.19683863  1.09903252 -1.12252223]
 [ 0.19683863  1.09903252 -1.12252223]
 [ 0.19683863  1.09903252 -1.12252223]
 [ 1.07770884 -1.47092581 -1.85934114]
 [ 1.07770884 -1.47092581 -1.85934114]
 [ 0.19683863  1.09903252 -1.12252223]
 [ 0.19683863  1.09903252 -1.12252223]
 [-0.34236383  1.67817557 -1.54652882]]
```

This converts each game location into a semantic field of features, in this case 3.

## Actual implementation of Frozen Lake

Here is some code that does the original ask with **frozen lake**

#### imports

```
import tensorflow as tf

index_max = 10
features = 5
width = 4
size = width*width

x_data = [[4, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 3],
    [0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 4, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 3]]

y_data = [[0, 4, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 3],
    [0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 4, 1, 3]]

x_input = tf.placeholder( shape=[None,size] , dtype=tf.int32 )
y_ground = tf.placeholder( shape=[None,size] , dtype=tf.int32 )


embedding_vector = tf.Variable( tf.truncated_normal( [index_max, features] , dtype=tf.float32 ) )
embedding_vector_3_ranks = tf.reshape(embedding_vector, [1,index_max, features])

x_embedding = tf.nn.embedding_lookup(embedding_vector, x_input)

def conv_layer( x , layers_in=features , layers_out=features ):
  strides = [1, 1, 1, 1]
  w = tf.Variable( tf.truncated_normal([3,3,layers_in, layers_out], stddev=0.1, dtype=tf.float32) )
  b = tf.Variable( tf.constant(0.1, shape=[layers_out], dtype=tf.float32) )
  h = tf.nn.conv2d( x, w, strides=[1, 1, 1, 1], padding='SAME' ) + b
  return h # tf.nn.relu( h )

hidden = tf.reshape( x_embedding, [-1,width,width,features] )
hidden = tf.nn.relu( conv_layer( hidden ) )
hidden = tf.nn.relu( conv_layer( hidden ) )
hidden = tf.nn.relu( conv_layer( hidden ) )
y_output = tf.reshape( conv_layer( hidden ) , [-1,features] )


item_as_embedding = tf.tile( y_output , tf.constant([1,index_max]) )
item_as_embedding = tf.reshape( item_as_embedding , [-1,index_max,features] )

item_distance_to_embedding = tf.square( embedding_vector_3_ranks - item_as_embedding )
item_distance_to_embedding = tf.reduce_mean( item_distance_to_embedding , -1 )
item_distance_to_embedding = tf.reshape( item_distance_to_embedding, [-1,index_max] )

y_estimate = tf.arg_max( -1.0 * tf.reduce_mean( tf.square( tf.reshape( embedding_vector, [1,index_max, features]) - item_as_embedding ) , -1 ) , 1 )
mask = tf.reshape( tf.one_hot(y_ground,index_max, dtype=tf.float32) , [-1,index_max] )
error = tf.reduce_sum( mask * item_distance_to_embedding , -1 )
learn = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(0.001).minimize(error)


sess = tf.Session()
sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer() )

for _ in range(20) :
    feed_dict = { x_input : x_data, y_ground : y_data }
    print sess.run(y_estimate,feed_dict).reshape([-1,size]) , sess.run(tf.reduce_sum(error,-1),feed_dict)
    for _ in range(20) :
      sess.run(learn,feed_dict)
```

Comment: Final tip: Yes this is something I have been arguing about, I agree that the encoding should be one-hot.

I think I put too much unnecessary detail in my question. An actor critic network will later be applied to do the actual learning. I'm more wondering whether or not its possible/how to make a cnn output, for example, a pixel array rather than just a classification (single) value.

Comment: **UPDATE** if you had **LOTS** of numbers (unique pieces?) then you could use something like a concept vector for each in much the same way the Word2Vec does.  In this case the number is a lookup to the pieces Vector which encodes a variety of stats.  You wouldn't do a 1-hot incoding, you'd do a embedding_lookup (line tf.nn.embedding_lookup).  You'd be able to define thousands of unused embeddings with random initial weights.  When the unused number is used, it will start with the random weights and train them appropriately.

Comment: Yes I believe I was thinking of implementing that if I understand you correctly: each unique vector would be cast to a position on an "encoding vector" right? so for example  x =[4, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 3] could be cast as embedding = [1,0,0,... ], x =[0, 4, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 3] could be cast as embedding =  [0, 1, 0,...]? I also revised my question so perhaps take a look at it.

Comment: Thanks for all the help. In terms of embeddings, would it be smart to use 5 features for each game location? Since the max number of values a  location could have is 5 possible values? What is the "index_max" value for?

Comment: no.  The features is the number of unique properties a game location can have.  For example, may word processing programs use a 300 feature embedding for words to capture their complex semantic meaning.  No, you'd need maybe log of or sqrt of the number if different values as the number of features.  The index_max is the maximum value that will be in the game location.   Set it to 5,000 and you can have any number from 0 to 4999 in each game location.  For 5,000 different pieces try 20 features.  20 features would be A LOT.

Comment: I'll accept but you'd have to answer "Is this possible to create a convnet that returns an output of that format?" (see the q)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/147200/discussion-between-stacks-of-overflow-and-wontonimo).